# How to dynamic component change when the button is pressed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a parent component and a child component is displayed in it by default, how do I make it so that when I click on the Timeline, instead of my pie chart component, another component with a different diagram is displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CK0f.gif)

**parent.component.html**

```
        <div class="portfolio__column">
          <ul class="portfolio__select">
            <li class="portfolio__select-item">
              <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Breakdown</a>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio__select-item">
              <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Timeline</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="portfolio__row">
        <app-doughnut-chart></app-doughnut-chart>
      </div>
```

Comment: a routerLink is used when you has a `<router-outlet>`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/routing-overview). I don't know about your <app-doughnut-chart> component. I imagine need some data (an array of object) you need in (click) call to a function and change this data (In general is used a template reference variable to pass the function your component)

Comment: @Eliseo Maybe I described everything a little wrong, I want to make my <app-doughnut-chart></app-doughnut-chart> change to <app-line-chart></app-line-chart> when clicked

Comment: you has two approaches, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a routerPath like

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'line-chart', component: LineChartComponent },
  { path: 'doughnut-chart', component: DoughnutChartComponent }
];
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DoughnutChartComponent,LineChartComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And your appComponent like

```
<ul class="portfolio__select">
   <li class="portfolio__select-item">
      <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/line-chart']">Breakdown</a>
   </li>
   <li class="portfolio__select-item">
       <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/doughnut-chart']">Timeline</a>
   </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then, when your url is like `localhost:4200/doughnut-chart' you see the DougnnutChartComponent and when is` localhost:4200/line-chart' you see the LineChartComponent

Or you can take another approach that is not change the "url", simply use a variable "typeChart". In your .ts you define

```
typeChart:string='line'
```

And your .html like

```
    <ul class="portfolio__select">
       <li class="portfolio__select-item">
          <a [class.active]="typeChart=='line' (click)="typeChart='line' >Breakdown</a>
       </li>
       <li class="portfolio__select-item">
           <a [class.active]="typeChart=='doughnut' (click)="typeChart='doughnut'">Timeline</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
<app-doughnut-chart *ngIf="typeChart=='doughnut'></app-doughnut-chart>
<app-line-chart *ngIf="typeChart=='line'></app-line-chart>
```

Well, this last approach can be if you create a app-dashboard-component like

```
@Input()typeChart="line" //<--in .ts

<app-doughnut-chart *ngIf="typeChart=='doughnut'></app-doughnut-chart>
<app-line-chart *ngIf="typeChart=='line'></app-line-chart>
```

And your mainComponent

```
   <ul>
    ...
   </ul>
   <app-dashboard-component [typeChart]="typeChart">
   </app-dashboard-component>
```

In the first approach you use [router](https://angular.io/guide/router), in the second one you use  [*ngIf](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-shorthand) structural directive. See that are two completely different approaches

Comment: Thanks, I've already done using load children in routes